# How to get end date from start date, start time and finish time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to find the end date of the Events in SQL. Following is the example of the data I have.

```
EventDate   EventStartTime    EventEndTime
01/01/2015  14:17             16:50
04/01/2015  19:20             22:00
17/01/2015  22:30             03:35
17/02/2015  22:50             03:35
30/05/2015  23:30             01:50
01/06/2015  11:40             14:50
```

Output I want:

```
EventDate   EventStartTime  EventEndTime    EventEndDate
01/01/2015  14:17           16:50           01/01/2015
04/01/2015  19:20           22:00           04/01/2015
17/01/2015  22:30           03:35           18/01/2015
17/02/2015  22:50           03:35           18/02/2015
30/05/2015  23:30           01:50           31/05/2015
01/06/2015  11:40           14:50           01/06/2015
```

If someone has some idea how to code this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You've asked for a solution in SQL, so please don't remove the SQL tags.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question??

Comment: If you can't explain how _you_ determine the `EventEndDate` then it will be awfully hard for you, or us, to implement the logic in code. Please explain the algorithm you are using. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. We wouldn't want to waste time assuming that all of the columns are `NVarChar(666)` when they _might_ be more appropriate data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only I can figure out from your question that if `END DATE` is lower than `START DAY` that is next day. So my query will be:

```
SELECT 
    EventDate,
    EventStartTime,
    EventEndTime,
    CASE 
        WHEN EventEndTime < EventStartTime THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EventDate) ELSE EventDate
    END AS EventEndDate
FROM 
    Events
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it through `case when` expression. If EventEndDate is smaller than EventStartDate then add one day with the EventDate and if EventEndDate is bigger than EventStartDate then select EventDate as EventStartDate (according to your output).

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table events(EventDate date,   EventStartTime time,    EventEndTime time);
 insert into events values('2015-01-01',  '14:17',             '16:50');
 insert into events values('2015-01-04',  '19:20',             '22:00');
 insert into events values('2015-01-17',  '22:30',             '03:35');
 insert into events values('2015-02-17',  '22:50',             '03:35');
 insert into events values('2015-05-30',  '23:30',             '01:50');
 insert into events values('2015-06-01',  '11:40',             '14:50');
```

Query:

```
 select EventDate,EventStartTime,EventEndTime, 
 (case when EventEndTime>=EventStartTime then EventDate else dateadd(day,1,EventDate) end)EventStartDate
 from events
```

Output:

| EventDate | EventStartTime | EventEndTime | EventEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 14:17:00.0000000 | 16:50:00.0000000 | 2015-01-01 |
| 2015-01-04 | 19:20:00.0000000 | 22:00:00.0000000 | 2015-01-04 |
| 2015-01-17 | 22:30:00.0000000 | 03:35:00.0000000 | 2015-01-18 |
| 2015-02-17 | 22:50:00.0000000 | 03:35:00.0000000 | 2015-02-18 |
| 2015-05-30 | 23:30:00.0000000 | 01:50:00.0000000 | 2015-05-31 |
| 2015-06-01 | 11:40:00.0000000 | 14:50:00.0000000 | 2015-06-01 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c11b8b60ea968c1c873f994fd6e7a441)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select EventDate ,EventStartTime,EventEndTime
,(
case when cast(EventStartTime as date)> cast(EventEndTime as date) 
then cast(cast(EventDate  as datetime) +1 as date)
else cast(EventDate  as date)
end
) EventEndDate
from TableName
```

try this it will work if i understand you.